# Checking Resume Capability with HttpWebRequest Method

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, download, httpwebresponse

This is the code I'm using:

```
private bool CheckPartialDL(String url)
{
    HttpWebRequest hwr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    hwr.Method = "HEAD";
    hwr.AddRange(0);

    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse hwbresp = (HttpWebResponse)hwr.GetResponse();
        if (hwbresp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PartialContent)
        {
            hwbresp.Close();
            return true;
        }

    }//end of try

    catch (WebException wbe)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(wbe.Message, "Error");
    }//end of catch

    return false;

}//end of Check
```

But server returned the following error:

The remote server returned an error : (416) requested range not satisfiable.

I'm going to download the following file form :

http://windowsclient.net/sitefiles/1000/wpf/videos/source-code/creatingavideoapp-part1.zip

when I used IDM to check resume capability, idm showed that it is available.

So where I'm wrong with presented code?

Comment: Minor issue, but FYI: WebRequest is part of .NET, not part of C#.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link which has some information

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E416.html

Now i have a little knowledge of Resumable downloads and how they work, so what I see is
you are not providing the correct range of bytes to be downloaded for the file.

Let's say file has size of 1500 bytes.
You must set range to something like from 150 - to 324.
and ofcourse the range must not be more than 1500 :)

So I think you are not providing it with a suitable range of data to be retrieved.

More, check this link question, it's specifying range
 of bytes
[HTTP Request with multiple Ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2293461/448407)

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is a couple of years old now but I just had the exact same issue (and similar code) and the problem seems to be that you can't have both "Method = 'HEAD'" and AddRange() as removing the call to AddRange works fine.

Edit - This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549051/http-head-request-with-range-header) confirms it:

> "A server must ignore a Range header field received with a request
>   method other than GET"