# HTTP HEAD request with Range Header

Tags: http, iis-7, http-headers

I am working on a DLNA Server using IIS as Server for media. Some DLNA Client sends a http HEAD 
request with a range Header :

```
Command: HEAD
```

+ URI: /RicDLNA/Streamer.ashx?media=/Videos/Guca%20Distant%20Trumpet/Gucha%20Distant%20Trumpet.mp4
    ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.1
    Host:  192.168.1.100
    range: bytes=0-
    transferMode.dlna.org:  Streaming
    HeaderEnd: CRLF

I respond only with "Accept-Ranges Bytes". But IIS delivers a statuscode 416 error. It looks that this error Status prevents the client to continue.

1. Is it allowed to send such a range Header in a HEAD request ?
2. What shall i response that the client  knows that ranges are supported and invoiding the IIS generated statuscode 416.
3. Is there a possibility to override bad IIS statuscode with an OK status ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I respond only with "Accept-Ranges Bytes"? What is the response that you're sending?

Answer (score 3):

In [ietf.org RFC7233](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7233) section [3.1 Range](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7233#section-3.1) you can find the excerpt

> A server MUST ignore a Range header field received with a request method other than GET

To me this means as much as : you can make a range-request with a HEAD command, but your server must ignore it.

Comment: There is no "w3c" spec for HTTP.

And no; what RFC 7233 says is that recipients need to ignore it on methods other than GET, nothing else.

Comment: @JulianReschke, now that I read it again, you are right. I am not native English, but I will change it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.0 will accept HEAD requests containing Range header (and will return status 206 expected by some media players such as the Popcorn Hour A-100).

I recently needed to make IIS 7.5 treat those requests the same as IIS 6.0 / 7.0, and was able to do so using the Beta http.sys v6.1.7000.0 and pre-Beta static.dll v6.1.6801.0 (driver signature enforcement must be circumvented on 64-bit versions of Windows)